# Is there a way to get network statistics such as speed, latency in an electron js app?

Tags: javascript, electron, network-programming

I have an electron JS app and there is a requirement to log network statistics.
We need parameters like network speed(Min and max network speed accessible over a period of few seconds), latency and other general network stats of the network to which the app is connected.
I checked through electron docs and general javascript methods to get the same, but unable to find anything related to the above.

Comment: have you checked this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-speed

Comment: @HarshMakwana Yes. But the library requires adding a remote URL to upload/download a file which is not a feasible solution inside our current application. I was looking for other ways(if available) to get network information.